# How to set custom endpoints in amazon ios sdk for presigning urls?

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I am trying to get presigned url for these music files from amazon server , I have working code of android but couldn't find a way in Objective-C to do this.

```
public static String getPreSignedURL(String url) {
java.util.Date expiration = new java.util.Date();
long msec = expiration.getTime();
msec += 1000 * 60 * 5; // 5 minutes
expiration.setTime(msec);

AWSCredentials myCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(
AppConstants.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AppConstants.AWS_SECRET_KEY_ID);
AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(myCredentials);
s3client.setEndpoint(AppConstants.ENDPOINT_S3);
GeneratePresignedUrlRequest request = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(
AppConstants.BUCKET_NAME, url.replace(AppConstants.OBJECT_NAME_FILTER, ""));
request.setExpiration(expiration);
URL objectURL = s3client.generatePresignedUrl(request);
return objectURL.toString();
}
```

This above code is in android.

```
var presignedUrl: AWSTask = AWSTask()
let expiration = NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(5*60)


let credential = AWSStaticCredentialsProvider.init(accessKey: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, secretKey: AWS_SECRET_KEY_ID)
let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration.init(region:.USEast1, credentialsProvider: credential)

//print("%@",configuration.endpoint)
//let regionTp = AWSRegionType(s)

AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
let urlBuilder = AWSS3PreSignedURLBuilder.defaultS3PreSignedURLBuilder()


let preSignedURLRequest = AWSS3GetPreSignedURLRequest.init()

preSignedURLRequest.key = "10488/01-New_Jack_City_hq.mp3"
preSignedURLRequest.bucket = "damixhub"
preSignedURLRequest.expires = expiration
preSignedURLRequest.HTTPMethod = .GET
presignedUrl = urlBuilder.getPreSignedURL(preSignedURLRequest)
```

This is what I am doing in ios till now but urls have significant difference and I get accessdenied error possibly because I havent mentioned custom end points.

Please let me know if you know solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this using version 1 of amazon sdk.
Just write pod "AWSiOSSDK" if you are using cocoa pods , if you want to do it manually then you need to get it from github [get it here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios-v1)

Note - As amazon doesnt provide this functionality in version 2 of sdk I have to use this deprecate version.